# Hibernate 4 SessionFactory-scoped interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor, sessionfactory

My Java applications uses Hibernate with a SessionFactory-scoped interceptor in order to change data before storing in the database.

```
myConfiguration.setInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
SessionFactory sf = myConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
```

With the release 4.0 of hibernate they changed the concept of using the class Configuration.

So my new approach is:

```
final ServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
srb.configure(...);                // Hibernate configuration
final ServiceRegistry sr = srb.buildServiceRegistry();
final MetadataSources mds = new MetadataSources(sr);
mds.add...();                      // All the meta data configurations
final Metadata md = mds.buildMetadata();
SessionFactory sf = md.buildSessionFactory();
```

**I have not found a point where to set the interceptor with this new approach.
Any recommendations on how to set a SessionFactory-scoped interceptor?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
final Metadata md = mds.buildMetadata();
SessionFactory sf = md.getSessionFactoryBuilder().with(interceptor).buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the solution. Unfortunately, there were no Javadocs in Hibernate documenting this feature. Thank you very much, dimitrijer!